# HMC5883L stops reading when x-axis value get to positive value

Tags: i2c, c, avr, debugging

I've been looking for a solution for this problem for quite a time I tried different I2C libraries; like,

> I2C master library using hardware TWI interface
>   * Author:   Peter Fleury

But the same problem, I think my problem is in the HMC5883L_my library.

Update: I have to mention that I'm including `I2C_TWSR_Check();` function to check the status of the I2C operations success in the HMC5883L library in `int16_t data_read (int16_t *results_ptr);` function, and as a result I get a successful operations all the time. But, the problem is when the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE is open and I'm watching the values and moving the module with different vectors, as soon as x-axis changes from -ve to +ve values, the serial monitor stops and I have to close it and open it again.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "HMC5883L_my.h"
#include "I2C.h"

int16_t results[3];

void HMC5883L_init (void)
{
  I2C_start(HMC5883L_write);
  I2C_tx(Configuration_Register_A);
  I2C_tx(0x78);
  I2C_tx(0x20);
  I2C_tx(0x00);
  I2C_stop();
}

int16_t data_read (int16_t *results_ptr)
{
  uint16_t lsb,msb;
  int16_t status_of_process = 0;

  I2C_start(HMC5883L_write);
  I2C_TWSR_Check();
  I2C_tx(Data_Output_X_MSB_Register);
  I2C_TWSR_Check();
  I2C_stop();

  I2C_start(HMC5883L_read);
  I2C_TWSR_Check();

  msb = I2C_rx();
  lsb = I2C_rx();
  I2C_TWSR_Check();

  results[0] = msb << 8 | lsb;

  Serial.print("x-axis = ");
  Serial.println(results[0]);

  msb = I2C_rx();
  lsb = I2C_rx();
  I2C_TWSR_Check();

  results[1] = msb << 8 | lsb;

  Serial.print("z-axis = ");
  Serial.println(results[1]);

  msb = I2C_rx();
  lsb = I2C_rx();
  I2C_TWSR_Check();
  results[2] = msb << 8 | lsb;

  Serial.print("y-axis = ");
  Serial.println(results[2]);
  I2C_TWSR_Check();
  I2C_stop();
  Serial.println();
  return status_of_process;
}

void HMC5883L_read_reg (uint8_t reg)
{
  uint8_t reg_dat;
  I2C_start(HMC5883L_write);
  I2C_tx(reg);
  I2C_start(HMC5883L_read);
  reg_dat = I2C_rx();
  I2C_stop();
  Serial.println(reg_dat);
}
```

As you can see I put `I2C_TWSR_Check();` after each I2C operation to see if there's any problem during read operation but I can't see any problem when the module stops reading if x-axis value get to positive region.

This is my I2C library but I don't think there's a serious problem with it because it worked with other I2C modules without any problem.

```
/*
 * I2C_Library.c
 *
 * Created: 6/6/2017 12:34:39 AM
 * Author : wolfrose
 */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "I2C.h"

void I2C_init(void)
{
    //set SCL to 100kHz
    TWSR = 0x00;
    TWBR = 0x48;
    //enable TWI
    TWCR = (1<<TWEN);
}

void I2C_start(uint8_t address)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);
    while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    TWDR = address;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
    while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
}

void I2C_stop(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
}

void I2C_tx(uint8_t data)
{
    TWDR = data;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
    while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
}

uint8_t I2C_rx(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
    while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    return TWDR;
}

void I2C_TWSR_Check(void)
{
  uint8_t Status;
  Status = TWSR & 0xF8;
  switch(Status)
  {
    /////////////// MASTER TRANSMITTER //////////////
    case 0x08:
    Serial.println("Start is OK");
     break;
    case 0x10:
    Serial.println("Re start");
     break;
    case 0x18:
    Serial.println("SLA+W OK ACK");
     break;
    case 0x20:
    Serial.println("SLA+W no ACK");
     break;
    case 0x28:
    Serial.println("data TX OK ACK");
     break;
    case 0x30:
    Serial.println("data TX OK no ACK");
     break;
    case 0x38:        // arbitration lost in SLA+W or data TX
    Serial.println("arbitration lost in SLA+W or data TX");
     break;

    /////////////// MASTER RECEIVER //////////////
    case 0x40:
    Serial.println("SLA+R OK ACK");
     break;
    case 0x48:
    Serial.println("SLA+R OK NO ACK");
     break;
    case 0x50:
    Serial.println("data RX OK ACK");
     break;
    case 0x58:
    Serial.println("data RX OK NO ACK");
     break;

     default:
     Serial.println("Error");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://hackaday.com/2017/07/29/everything-you-need-to-know-about-logic-probes/

Comment: are any of the error messages being displayed?

Comment: I don't see where the 'wait for ack/nak' on transmit nor where the 'send ack/nak' after receive is being handled.  Is that handled in the hardware?  if not, it needs to be handled in the code.

Comment: @Jot No I haven't, I'm downloading the video right now it should be interesting I'm thinking now of how powerful logic analyzers to detect errors, as with my current configuration for debugging I'm applying Arduino IDE and the serial monitor should be enough to know what is going on but actually I couldn't detect the problem.

Comment: @user3629249 No, everything looks working properly but as soon as x-axis value gets to positive it stops reading and I have to close the serial monitor and open it again to enable reading again.

Comment: @user3629249 >> 2nd comment, no in software it's 'I2C_TWSR_Check();', it's in the I2C library.

Comment: The function: `I2C_TWSR_Check()` does NOT wait for the ACK/NAK nor does it send that byte.  Infact the function checks the status register to see if a proper response from the slave was received, when bytes were sent.  After thinking it over, I suspect the hardware is handling the ACK/NAK communication

Comment: since your calling the `I2C_TWSR_Check()` function after each communication is complete, you should be seeing the output from this: `Serial.println("SLA+R OK ACK");` all the time there is a successful receive communication and the output from this: `Serial.println("data TX OK ACK");` all the time there is a successful transmit communication.  Your question does not mention this output.  please apply an EDIT to update

Comment: Suggest printing the whole status register before checking the bits, so you/we know what the actual status is, including when the X axis transitions from negative to positive

Comment: why is the posted code sending start and stop for each byte when sending/receiving a multibyte value.  The normal way that I2C works (after establishing communication) is the master sends start, command, stop.  then the slave sends ack then if the command was to send data then the slave sends start, data ... data, stop.  then the master sends ACK.  A very similar sequence is used when the master wants to send data.

Comment: @user3629249 First of all, thank you so much for the replies and the help. Secondly, for your first concern about ACK/NAK, well the `I2C_TWSR_Check()` function checks if the ACK/NAK for data or address is received or not that what I think is the process for checking ACK/NAK. But I think you mean something else, well I'm thinking of `while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));` where this bit is responsible for each I2C operation completion, could this bit is what you mean? Because I don't know anything about handling ACK/NAK by software or hardware.

Comment: `Suggest printing the whole status register before checking the bits, so you/we know what the actual status is, including when the X axis transitions from negative to positive`, I don't understand what you mean exactly, the status register is linked with the specified values for each I2C master values in the 328p datasheet, anything else is considered as an error in the last function in the I2C library.

Comment: @user3629249 `why is the posted code sending start and stop for each byte when sending/receiving a multibyte value ... rest of comment`, I know that, I'm actually not applying a stop function after each byte send/receive, if you see the `void HMC5883L_init (void)`, it sends multiple bytes because one member told me that i can do it in two ways, whether to send a stop after each byte of send multiple ones with one stop. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39373/hmc5883l-not-working-in-continuous-mode/39383#39383

Comment: Suggest reading/understanding the I2C bus specification.  Here is a link [I2C](http://i2c.info/i2c-bus-specification)

Comment: I think I'm working pretty well in my I2C library, because I applied Peter Fleury's I2C library as I mentioned in the main topic and the same problem happened. I think my problem is in the HMC5883L library.

Comment: I'm working now with a new strategy, which to apply twi main library.